# How to delete a file from github repository after deleting the same file on local machine?

Tags: git, github

I am new to GitHub.I have a project on my local machine as well as on Git now there was a unwanted file in that project folder so I deleted that now I want to delete the same folder from my git repository of same project how do I do that please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted your file locally, then by issuing `git status` you'll see it as deleted (a `D` will appear before the name of the file). All you have to do to also delete it on your remote is just work as per usual (`add` the deleted file, `commit` it, and`push` it to your remote repo)